# Why has "pence" been used in this sentence, not "pences"?

Tags: word-choice

> You can then open the chest, and take from it as many pence as you please, ***they are only copper pence***, but if you would rather have silver money, you must go into the second chamber.
>
> Source: *The Tinder Box* by Hans Christian Anderson

Is that boldface correct grammatically?

Why is that "pence", not "pences"?

Comment: Partially irrelevant pedantry: Andersen's original story was written in Danish and so does not say "pence". The word he used was _"skillinger"_ which is cognate to _shilling_, though the value of the actual Danish skilling coin that circulated in Andersen's time seems to have been closer to an English penny than to a shilling.

Comment: Exchange rates aside, the _skilling_ was the smallest named unit of currency in circulation, and the context makes it clear that Andersen was not using the word to refer to a particular _value_, but as a generic word for small common coins. Thus a truer translation to modern English would probably be "pennies" rather than "pence"

Comment: You could have started by looking up *pence* in a dictionary.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Because *pence* is plural. It is historically a plural of *penny*, and is still used that way in some contexts in British English.

Specifically, it is normal when referring to value: "one penny, two pence" (though many people say "one p, two p")

It is not currently used when referring to individual coins: most people would say "there is a pile of pennies on the table", not "there is a pile of pence on the table". In that respect, the passage you quote is archaic.

Comment: Is it archaic though, or just poorly translated? I mean, did people use to use "pence" rather than pennies" when referring to coins in this way?

Comment: Yes, they did. Example from George Eliot, 1868 (quoted in OED): " A poor pocket-picking scoundrel, who will steal your loose pence while you are listening round the platform."

Comment: I believe the term *p* is specific to the British new pence (i.e. post-decimalization). I thought it was adopted to distinguish it from the pre-decimal penny (whose abbreviation was *d*), and I don't think it would be used for pennies of another currency.

Comment: Saying "one p, two p" only started when the UK converted to decimal currency in 1972, probably because during the changeover it was long winded to keep saying "old pence" and "new pence" (the new ones were worth 2.4 times as much as the old ones!)

Comment: @Rupe It's not archaic. It is still often used in British English. You can say "I only have 15 pence" or "I only have 15 p", but you would *never* say "I only have 15 pennies", unless you meant "I only have 15 one-penny coins" and not "I only have coins worth £0.15" (for example one 10p and one 5p coin).

Comment: I used to hear fruit and vegetable stallholders in Brixton Market saying, e.g.  "three dee" for the pre-decimalisation sum of 3d (three old pence). This would have been c. 1957 onwards.

Comment: @alephzero: that's exactly the point I made in my answer. Those of us who say "penny" rather than "p" _do_ say "pence" for a value, but not referring to coins.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I was only 16 at decimalisation, but I don't remember anybody saying "dee" for (old) pence. The word "three-pence" was pronounced "thruppence" or "threppence". The symbol "p" came in for "new pence" in 1971, and I remember some people being horrified when people started pronouncing it "pee" insted of "(new) penny/pence".

Comment: My parents, especially my mother, had Fortnum and Mason notions, but, unfortunately, a Brixton Market budget. They were at great pains to stop me talking like a Cockney, which had the probably unintended effect of making me very interested in local speech.

Comment: @alephzero for a thought experiment imagine a pile of 1p coins on the table and you were asked how many coins were on the table and you had to answer in a full sentence what would you say. I would answer "There are 15 pennies on the table" or "there are 15 coins on the table" not "there are 15 pence on the table" that would require it to change to "there is 15 pence on the table" and that would be a single value not a count of the coins.

Comment: @alephzero I think you may have misread things. It's the _quoted passage_ that Colin referred to as archaic. And whether or not it's archaic (which he's answered), it definitely doesn't sound like modern British English.